# existence of a subgroup of a solvable group G of order d for any divisor d of |G|, with d<|G|^(1/2)

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a solvable group of order $n$ and $d<\sqrt{n}$ be any divisor of $n$. Is there any subgroup of $G$ of order $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $A_4$ is solvable and has no subgroup of size $6$, so $A_4\times \mathbf{Z}/101\mathbf{Z}$ is a counterexample for you.

Comment: nice answer, but why $101\mathbb{Z}$, I think $5\mathbb{Z}$ is enough.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel I wasn't sure whether $6 < \sqrt{|A_4|5}$, but I was quite sure that $6 < \sqrt{|A_4|101}$.

Comment: Thank you for the example.